# Конвертация рублей в биткоины по курсу

Tags: bitcoin

У меня есть курс: 420 943.9960

Как правильно составить решение от 1 рубля по такому курсу

Comment: `У меня есть курс: 420 943.9960` Это стоимость 1го биткоина?

Comment: @LLENN ага такие курсы примерно

Answer (score 5):

Вспомним школьную математику, пропорции:

- 420943.9960 руб. - это 1 BTC
- 1 руб. - это X BTC

Получается равенство:

```
420943.9960 / 1 = 1 / Х
```

Что эквивалентно:

```
1 / 420943.9960 = X / 1
```

А значит требуемое число вычисляется как:

```
Х = 1 / 420943.9960
```

На один рубль можно купить 0.0000023 биткоина или 2.3756 [μBTC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Units).

Можно не выводить, а запомнить [простую формулу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). Результат не меняется.